# File 'latexdiff.sty' not found \usepackage (Texlive)

Tags: latexdiff, texlive-2018

I have used the ***latexdiff*** to generate a diff.tex, and it works fine. But when i try to generate a pdf file, the texstudio tell me that **File 'latexdiff.sty' not found \usepackage**.
The following is the introduction section about the diff.tex

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,pra,superscriptaddress,amsmath,showpacs,tightenlines]{revtex4}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL old.tex   Fri Oct 25 11:25:57 2019
%DIF ADD new.tex   Sat Nov  2 00:52:19 2019

%DIF 13a13
\usepackage{latexdiff} %DIF > 
%DIF -------
\usepackage{float}
%DIF 15-16d16
%DIF < 
%DIF < 
%DIF -------
```

and some new updates

```
\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF HYPERREF PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFdeltex{#1}}{}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\DIFscaledelfig}{0.5}
%DIF HIGHLIGHTGRAPHICS PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{settobox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newsavebox{\DIFdelgraphicsbox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newlength{\DIFdelgraphicswidth} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newlength{\DIFdelgraphicsheight} %DIF PREAMBLE
% store original definition of \includegraphics %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOincludegraphics}{\includegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\DIFaddincludegraphics}[2][]{{\color{blue}\fbox{\DIFOincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\DIFdelincludegraphics}[2][]{% %DIF PREAMBLE
\sbox{\DIFdelgraphicsbox}{\DIFOincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
\settoboxwidth{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{\DIFdelgraphicsbox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\settoboxtotalheight{\DIFdelgraphicsheight}{\DIFdelgraphicsbox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\scalebox{\DIFscaledelfig}{% %DIF PREAMBLE
\parbox[b]{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{\usebox{\DIFdelgraphicsbox}\\[-\baselineskip] \rule{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{0em}}\llap{\resizebox{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{\DIFdelgraphicsheight}{% %DIF PREAMBLE
\setlength{\unitlength}{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}% %DIF PREAMBLE
\begin{picture}(1,1)% %DIF PREAMBLE
\thicklines\linethickness{2pt} %DIF PREAMBLE
{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}\put(0,0){\framebox(1,1){}}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}\put(0,0){\line( 1,1){1}}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}\put(0,1){\line(1,-1){1}}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
\end{picture}% %DIF PREAMBLE
}\hspace*{3pt}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddbegin}{\DIFaddbegin} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddend}{\DIFaddend} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelbegin}{\DIFdelbegin} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelend}{\DIFdelend} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddbegin}{\DIFOaddbegin \let\includegraphics\DIFaddincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddend}{\DIFOaddend \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelbegin}{\DIFOdelbegin \let\includegraphics\DIFdelincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelend}{\DIFOaddend \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddbeginFL}{\DIFaddbeginFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddendFL}{\DIFaddendFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelbeginFL}{\DIFdelbeginFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelendFL}{\DIFdelendFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{\DIFOaddbeginFL \let\includegraphics\DIFaddincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddendFL}{\DIFOaddendFL \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{\DIFOdelbeginFL \let\includegraphics\DIFdelincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelendFL}{\DIFOaddendFL \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
```

PS: I have install the **Texlive**. But I not found the corresbonding file in the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete the line 
`\usepackage{latexdiff.sty}`

Such a style file is certainly not part of the standard latexdiff which defines all the commands it needs simply by adding them to the diff file. You can see them in the second code snippet you posted.

From the way it looks this line was added to the 'new' file in any case. (Standard) latexdiff does not add such a line.

Comment: Thanks. Follow your advice, such probelem is solved.

Comment: Thanks. You can accept the answer then (there must be a button for this) on your question page.